# android Mail intent not working with special characters

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am using mail sending intent action in android with some special characters in subject.
below is the code which I am trying.

```
  encodedMailContent = "mailto:?subject=get2% SMA&RT$ rebate&body=get 2% SMART$";
  Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(encodedMailContent));
  startActivity(intent);
```

That is I am using some special characters like '#', '&' in subject.
**But its showing till that special character and truncating the remaining in subject like get2% SMA.**

Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Resolved this by use the Uri Encode values of those special characters in mail content like below.
Replace '&' with %26 and '#' with %23.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`URLEncoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode the subject part in your `mailto:` URI.

Comment: i already tried this. it didnt worked for me. thanks for replay